# TsLint complains about calling top level async method

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, tslint, ecmascript-2016

I've configured TsLint to warn for unhandled promises:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-floating-promises": [
          true,
          "Promise",
          "Q.Promise" 
        ],
    }
}
```

The code follows the [standard template for build tasks for vsts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/stepbystep.md):

```
async function run() {
  try {
      ...
  } catch (err) {
      tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message);
  }
}

run(); // tslint complains here...
```

TsLint now complains that the promise is unhandled, but I can't add await before `run`... I don't want to mix run with `.then` as it's introducing another async paradigm...

```
ERROR: C:/Users/JesseHouwing/Source/Repos/....ts[16, 5]: Promises must be handled appropriately
```

These tasks are executed in Node, not awaiting the `run` method, it's working fine... Can I safely suppress this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that I can safely suppress the value by using:

```
async function run() {
  try {
      ...
  } catch (err) {
      tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message);
  }
}

void run(); // tslint no longer complains here and it's explicit :)
```

Inserting `void` in front of the top level `run` method seems to solve this.